# Сложение массивов в массиве - циклом JS

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

Нужна помощь. Есть большой массив, из консоли, вот такой:

```
(90) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), 
Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
> 0: Array(2)
   0: (4) [12, 14, 15, 16]
   1: (4) [10, 11, 12, 14]
   length: 2
> 1: Array(2)
   0: (4) [12, 14, 15, 16]
   1: (4) [9, 10, 11, 11]
   length: 2
```

Мне нужно сложить два массива в многомерном массиве.
Т.е. нужно сложить arrMas[0][0] + arrMas[0][1], это: [12, 14, 15, 16] + [10, 11, 12, 14], результат: [22, 25, 27, 30];
arrMas[1][0] + arrMas[1][1], это: [12, 14, 15, 16] + [9, 10, 11, 11], результат: [21, 24, 26, 27];  и т.д.
Результатом должен быть такой же массив, но уже со сложенным внутри себя массивами. Как мне это сделать циклом?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1xpucf

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать например так:

```js
const arr = [
  [
    [12, 14, 15, 16],
    [10, 11, 12, 14],
  ],
  [
    [12, 14, 15, 16],
    [9, 10, 11, 11],
  ],
  [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [10, 20, 30],
  ],
];

console.log(`arr`, arr);

const res = arr.map((item) =>
  item[0].map((_, idx) => item.reduce((a, b) => a + b[idx], 0))
);

console.log(`res`, res);
```